# MySQL запрос UPDATE с JOIN обновляет только одну строку

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с такой структурой:

```
create table orders(id int not null auto_increment primary key, payment varchar(64), type varchar(64), order_status varchar(64), amount float);
insert into orders(type, order_status, amount) values(2, 1, 50),(2, 1, 50),(5, 1, 50),(5, 1, 50),(5, 1, 50),(5, 1, 50),(5, 1, 50);
```

И есть вот такой запрос:

```
UPDATE 
  orders AS o 
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
      id, 
      payment, 
      type, 
      order_status, 
      amount, 
      @total := SUM(amount) 
    FROM 
      orders 
    WHERE 
      type = 5 
      AND order_status BETWEEN 1 AND 2 FOR UPDATE 
      ) AS n ON o.id = n.id 
SET 
  o.payment = 3
```

Суть запроса в том, чтобы он обновлял все значения колонки `payment`, которые попадают под условия в JOIN SELECT, а также выдавал значение переменной @total, в которой содержится сумма колонки `amount` в строках, также попадающих под условие в JOIN SELECT. В итоге, с таким запросом сумма в переменную @total попадает корректная, однако UPDATE обновляет только первую строку, попадающую под условия, а остальные нет. Но если убрать из запроса `@total := SUM(amount)`, то все обновляется как нужно. Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Как `@total := SUM(amount)` влияет на UPDATE и как нужно сделать, чтобы все работало правильно?

Этот пример на dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=c3a2ee25c6f4d4be3aca7508b6829321

Comment: `SUM` - это агрегат, а значит из набора строк сделает одну. Почему бы вам запрос не разбить на несколько? один обновляет, другой считает сумму

Comment: @ArchDemon, разбить на два запроса конечно же можно, но как можно это сделать именно в одном запросе?

Comment: вместо `SUM(amount) ` сделать подзапрос `SELECT SUM(amount) FROM ... WHERE ...`

Comment: @ArchDemon, Благодарю! Да, похоже подзапрос это единственный вариант, чтобы сделать это в одном запросе.

Comment: Но я бы не советовал так делать. Если планировщик не поймёт, что подзапрос возвращает один и тот же результат, потому что обрабатывает один и тот же набор данных, то сложность возрастёт до O(N+2), хотя можно обойтись двумя запросами

Comment: @ArchDemon, да, я согласен с вами и тоже думаю что все же лучше разбить на два запроса. Первый делает апдейт, а второй считает сумму и возможно сделать это в одной транзакции.